# Details on how to glue sheaves together using a sheaf on a base.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, proof-writing, proof-explanation, sheaf-theory

I am doing the following exercise 2.7D from Ravi Vakil's notes.

> Suppose $X = \bigcup U_i$ is an open cover of $X$, and we have sheaves $\mathscr F_i$ on $U_i$ along with isomorphisms $\phi_{ij} : \mathscr F_i|_{U_i \cap U_j} \to \mathscr F_j|_{U_i\cap U_j}$ (with
> $\phi_{ii}$ the identity) that agree on triple overlaps, i.e., $\phi_{jk} \circ \phi_{ij} = \phi_{ik}$ on $U_i \cap U_j \cap U_k$ (this is called the cocycle condition, for reasons we ignore). Show that these
> sheaves can be glued together into a sheaf $\mathscr F$ on $X$ (unique up to unique isomorphism), such that $\mathscr F|_{U_i} \cong \mathscr F_i$, and the isomorphisms over $U_i \cap U_j$ are the obvious ones.

The set of all open sets contained in $U_i$ for all $i \in I$, i.e., $\mathcal B=\{B \subset U_i\mid B \text{ is open}\}$, gives me a base for the topology on $X$.
I am trying to get a sheaf on the base and from it it can be extended to a sheaf on $X$.
I am having trouble defining this sheaf say $F$ on the base.

What I did: If I have an open set of the form $V \subseteq U_i$, then  I was going to let
$$
F(V) = F_i(V). 
$$

I thought this was right but I got confused because if $V$ happens to be also contained in $U_j$, then
$$
F(V) = F_j(V)
$$
also but we only know they are isomorphic to each other and not equal.
Could someone please give me a hint as how I can get around this issue?

Comment: [This](http://math.uchicago.edu/~chonoles/expository-notes/hartshorne-2.1.22.pdf) might help?

Comment: Choose one or the other arbitrarily and remember your choice.

Comment: @ZhenLin I see. I don't need axiom of choice or anything to do this by any chance do I?

Comment: It can be done without the axiom of choice, but then the construction becomes much more elaborate.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much!

Comment: @RobertCardona I will take a look. Thank you!